# Draw sharp tool / subdivide

Tags: sculpting, subdivision-surface

I made a head with the cube.

I added a cube and turned it into a sphere by subdivision surface but now I'm trying to sculpt the face, and I noticed that I can't use draw sharp tool because of the edges, because the faces are too large and they have distance between them.

Now whatever I do I can't subdivide the cube in a way that doesn't change the form of the shape . I even used the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> keyframe to raise the amount number of the surface but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set scale to 1 always whenever you sculpt
2. Don't use subdivision to sculpt. Use remesh or multiresolution modifier.

[image]